# A problem on bivariate random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification

Suppose we have absolutely continuous random vectors $X=(X_1,X_2)$ and $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)$. And we have $Y_i=a_iX_i+b_i$, and $a_i>0, b_i\geq 0$ $i=1,2$ . Let ${F}$ be a distribution function such that
${F}_X(x_1,x_2)=P(X_1\leq x_1,X_2\leq x_2).$
We know that $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}F_X(x_1,x_2)=f_X(x_1,x_2).$

Now, \begin{align}
F_Y(y_1,y_2)&=P(Y_1\leq y_1,Y_2\leq y_2)\\
&=P(a_1X_1+b_1\leq y_1,a_2X_2+b_2\leq y_2)\\
&=P(X_1\leq (y_1-b_1)/a_1,X_2\leq (y_2-b_2)/a_2)\\
&=F_X((y_1-b_1)/a_1,(y_2-b_2)/a_2)\\
\end{align}
Form here can we say that $f_Y(y_1,y_2)=f_X(x_1,x_2)$?
Thanks beforehand!

Comment: The question makes little sense. Use the notation  $F_X$ and $f_X$ for  CDF and PDF of $X$.

Comment: You  want to use notation $F_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)$ and $F_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$. Also it does not make sense to have the left-hand-side a function of $y_1,y_2$ while the right is a function of $x_1,x_2$. Keep everything in terms of $(y_1,y_2)$. When differentiating $F_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)$ you are neglecting the $(1/a_1)(1/a_2)$ factor.

Comment: The answer is no. Again, you need to keep everything in terms of $(y_1,y_2)$. Erase that last line $F_X(x_1,x_2)$ and never use $x_1,x_2$ variables. You need to differentiate with respect to $y_1,y_2$.

Comment: @Michael, thank you so much, how do we differentiate this $F_X((y_1-b_1)/a_1,(y_2-b_2)/a_2)$? I want to find the probability density function under the given condition.

Comment: Chain rule. First differentiate with respect to $y_1$ using the chain rule. If you want to start simpler, you may as well ask the same question in one dimension: If we have a random variable $X$ with CDF and PDF, and if $Y=aX+b$, how does the PDF of $Y$ relate to the PDF of $X$? There is a normalizing factor $1/|a|$.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I am very new in this field I have done similar things in one dimension, but I am very confused in two dimension things. Can you do for me please?

Comment: When you take $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}$ you can ignore the $(y_2-b_2)/a_2$ part. Imagine that $y_2$ is constant so you have a pure function of $y_1$, such as $g(y_1) = F_X((y_1-b_1)/a_1, (y_2-b_2)/a_2)$ so $$g'(y_1) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y_1} F_X((y_1-b_1)/a_1, (y_2-b_2)/a_2) \cdot (1/a_1)$$

Comment: Now considering the $g'(y_1)$ as a function of $y_2$ and other part is constant. Assuming $h(y_2)=g'(y_1) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y_1} F_X((y_1-b_1)/a_1, (y_2-b_2)/a_2) \cdot (1/a_1)$. Now, differentiating partially with respect to $y_2$
, we have $\frac{\partial h(y_2)}{\partial y_2}=\frac{\partial g'(y_1)}{\partial y_2}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y_2\partial y_1} F_X((y_1-b_1)/a_1, (y_2-b_2)/a_2) \cdot (1/(a_1a_2))$. So we have finally $f_Y(y_1,y_2)=\frac{1}{a_1a_2} f_X((y_1-b_1)/a_1, (y_2-b_2)/a_2)$. Am I right?